# Running Rosetta Stone in Wine

Tags: sound, wine

I am trying to run Rosetta Stone in wine but when I load it I get the following:

[image]

I am trying to run Rosetta Stone V 3. in WINE V 1.4

I installed WINE, then I used WINE to install Rosetta Stone and it seamed to install ok, meaning I got no errors. Then all I did was set my .exe files to be opened with WINE by default. After this I started Rosetta Stone and the above screen shot was the result. I do not know how to configure WINE properly so it may just need further configuration. I am just not sure...

Can someone please help?

Comment: What version of Rosetta Stone are you trying to use? If you look at [The Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1867) for Rosetta Stone it might give you some pointers as you haven't provided enough details on what you have already done. Additionally, you could edit your question and give us more information on what you have tried and what error messages that you have received. That would go a long way in helping us to help you. Right now, your question has a good deal of rhetoric and is lacking in technical detail. Hope the link helps.

Comment: Rant removed. If you got problems with help please post that on meta. Oh and you -do- understand wine and rosetta stone is not going to get a lot of people answering since most of us do not use wine and even less will use rosetta stone and even less will have seen this problem? And why do you not ask this on the wine forums. I would expect that the specialists regarding this to be there.

Comment: Hey Kevin I am running version 3 of Rosetta Stone. I am sorry for the lack of details. I was frustrated because I did not have enough reps to post an image so I got sidetracked. Thank you for the links and yes I will check them out... Rainzwind, I did not know about meta so thank you for the info. I am just frustrated is all, last time I used ubuntu they did not have all this rep stuff. I read up on it and now I understand why they do it though. I just want my reps now is all. Thanks both of you for your help...

Comment: @Kevin Bowen, Problem Solved... I was listening to rythmbox when I tried to install Rosetta Stone the first time and it would not detect the sound device. I tried again later when I was not listening to rythmbox and it installed just fine... Thank you guys for your all advice, information, and help!

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolved that. Please add your comment as an answer and accept it, when you get a chance as I have noticed a couple of other Rosetta Stone questions that don't have good answers and this question might be able to be used as a future reference. Additionally, you could possibly add this report to the WINE database to help others in the community. That's how this open source stuff works. ;-) Sorry about your initial frustration, but glad to see you reporting back on your solution. Good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved**...

What happened was, I was listening to rythmbox when I tried to install Rosetta Stone the first time and it would not detect the sound device. I tried again later when I was not listening to rythmbox and it installed just fine...